# Como enviar dados para o constructor?

Tags: android

Preciso que me ajudem a entender a parte da programação em objectos.

Precisava de passar um valor que não estivesse dentro do objecto teste para saber qual era a escolha do utilzador. 
Mas mais uma vez sou iniciante em objectos.

Como tenho que chamar na minha actividade principal para receber a escolha ?

```
public class organizadist {

    public organizadist()
    {

    }

    public teste[] inicializa(teste[] objecto) {
// o que eu queria receber
if (escolha==1){
// faz alguma coisa 
}
if (escolha==2){


//faz outra coisa 



    }


    public static class teste {
        public int ola;


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples aprendi isso ontem curiosamente.

**Na sua actividade :**

```
 organizadist enviadados = new organizadist();
                organizadist.Teste array [] = enviadados.inicializa(listaClothes ,  escolha);
```

**No seu constructor:**`

```
public teste[] inicializa(teste[] objecto , int escolha);
```

Comment: Acho que não está a funcionar pelos testes que fiz aqui mais tarde volto com mais info

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma para passar valor usando construtor.

```
public FrmDetalheRet(string pstrAba, int pnuNuped, int pnuCdRetPedVda)
{
   InitializeComponent();

  if (pstrAba == strConstReceb)            
     //this.dgvReceb.Columns["colCdPRod"].Visible = false;            
  if (pstrAba == strConstPed)          
     // this.dgvReceb.Columns["col2"].Visible = false;           

  string strMsg = string.Empty;
  bool booRetorno = false;

  BLLDetItPedv bLLDetItPedv = new BLLDetItPedv();
  DataTable  dt = bLLDetItPedv.SelectDadosDetItPedvDAL(out strMsg, out    booRetorno, pnuNuped, pnuCdRetPedVda);

  if (!booRetorno)
  {
     MessageBoxHelper.WarningMessage(strMsg);
     return;
  }
  else
  {
     PopulaTabela(dt);
  }
}

// Na chamada da classe você passa os parâmetros necessários para o construtor:
FrmDetalheRet frmDetalheRet = new FrmDetalheRet(strConstPed,(int)dgvPedido["colNuPed", dgvPedido.CurrentRow.Index].Value,                    (int)dgvPedido["colCdRetPedVda", dgvPedido.CurrentRow.Index].Value);
frmDetalheRet.Show();
```

No exemplo acima na classe eu faço algumas operções com os valores que foram passados como parâmetros.

Comment: Obrigado Lucas Queiroz Ribeiro, estou pegando o jeito de como postar código formato.